# class file for android.support.v4.app.Fragment not found error

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I was adding the feature of adding the profile picture in my app and for that I tried using glide
however when I run the app it points at that line of code and says the error as I have mentioned above
This is my code

```
 user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        userID=user.getUid();
        reference.child("Customer").child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Users usersnapshot=snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                if(usersnapshot!=null){
                    Map<String,Object> map=(Map<String, Object>)snapshot.getValue();
                    String username=usersnapshot.getUsername();
                    String Email=usersnapshot.getMail();//
                    Username.setText(username);
                    name=username;
                    mail=Email;
                    email.setText(Email);
                    button.setEnabled(!username.isEmpty()&&!Email.isEmpty());
                    if(map.get("profileImageUri")!=null){
                        profilepic=map.get("profileImageUri").toString();
                        Glide.with(getApplication()).load(profilepic).into(imageView);\\this is the line where it showed the error
                    }
                }

            }
```

these are my dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
}
```

Comment: try change your import to  `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`

Comment: The `getApplication()` on the line `Glide.with(getApplication()).load(profilepic).into(imageView);` come from which class ?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine i edited that but it says it isn't used at all

Comment: @sitatech it says Activity class